# How to close a Bootstrap popover by clicking a button within the popover itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Unfortunately I am struggling to get a Bootstrap popover (which opens on my page at a specific location) to close when clicking on a form html button (within the popover itself). I know there have been similar questions to this and believe me I have already attempted a few of the associated solutions to no avail...

I have the following Javascript code for opening a Bootstrap popover on my page at a specific element:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#bob').popover({

    title:"Reaction",
    html:true,
    content:html

}).popover('show')}, 1000);

// If a popover is open then can execute the following Javascript. Need to detect also which step clicked on...
$('#bob').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {            

    var close =  document.getElementById("yes");

    // if close button is clicked...
    close.addEventListener("click", function(){

        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("close button clicked");          

        $('#bob').popover('hide'); 

    }):

});
```

The associated html for the button within the popover is as follows:

```
<button id ="yes" data-toggle="clickover" class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right">Yes</button>
```

Unfortunately the above does not work.

I have also looked at other answers/solutions for this problem and have tried the following already to no avail:

```
<button id ="yes" data-toggle="clickover" class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" onclick="event.preventDefault(); $(&quot;id&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">Yes</button>
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could give me some clues/hints as to how I could get this to work.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

The code itself have mistake. You forgot to add # before the id selector

// If a popover is open then can execute the following Javascript. Need to detect also which step clicked on...

```
$("#"+id).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {            

   var close =  document.getElementById("yes");

   // if close button is clicked...
   close.addEventListener("click", function(){

       event.preventDefault();

       console.log("close button clicked");          


       $("#"+id).popover('hide'); 

    }):

});
```

Comment: How do you know what "id" variable contains? You're assuming it is only a number, but it can be a string in form "#number".

Comment: Ok, please see the above code edits I have made. I changed id to '#bob' and that still does not work. I was wondering if you have any further suggestions? Cheers

Comment: Ofcourse writing "number" I meant "identifier". Too much time with databases :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing - errors:

1. there is a colon instead of semicolon at the end of third line from
   the end,
2. here

   ```
   close.addEventListener("click", function(){

       event.preventDefault();
   ```

you forget to put `'event'` in function args.

And the main problem: you're trying to assign event handler `'shown.bs.popover'` too soon. Putting it in `document.ready` should solve the problem

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#bob').popover({

    title:"Reaction",
    html:true,
    content:html

}).popover('show')}, 1000);

$(function(){//<---ADD THIS
    // If a popover is open then can execute the following Javascript. Need to detect also which step clicked on...
    $('#bob').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {            

        var close =  document.getElementById("yes");

        // if close button is clicked...
        close.addEventListener("click", function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            console.log("close button clicked");          

            $('#bob').popover('hide'); 

        });

    });
});//<---ADD THIS
```

If you use `setTimeout` for the same reason (without it `$('#bob').popover()` was not working), change it by puttin it to `document.ready` block too. Don't rely on `setTimeout`.